# Wrong rendering order styled-components on Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, styled-components

I have problem with render order in styles with my styled-components.
In the screenshots below there are differences of chrome(1) styles render and safari(2).
Are there any solutions to this problem?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nsi3.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfQFo.png)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue by sharing a codepen/codesandbox? What version of styled-components? What versions of browsers?

Comment: It's just a normal styled component, nothing wired. It happened with any styled component.
"styled-components": "5.0.1"
Safari version 13.0.5 (15608.5.11)

Comment: I'd create a codesandbox and open an issue in the stopped styled-components repo.

Comment: where you open issue?)

Comment: Search for issues here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues and if nobody had a similar one, open a new issue here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/new